# BMS supertranslations and integral identity in arXiv:1603.07706

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, symmetry, quantum-gravity

Looking at the paper [1603.07706](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07706) we see that infinitesimal BMS supertranslations are generated by:
$$
\xi = f\partial_u - \frac{1}{r}\left(D^zf\partial_z + D^\bar{z}f\partial_\bar{z}\right) + \frac{1}{2}D^2f\partial_r, \quad D^2 = 2D^zD_z
$$
We also see that acting on $C_{zz}$ (Weyl curvature), this supertranslation gives: $\delta_fC_{zz} = fN_{zz} - 2D^2_zf$.

The first term is trivial, since the Bondi news is defined as $N_{zz} = \partial_uC_{zz}$, but I can't work out the second term. Is there a resource where this term is explicitly worked out?

**Question 2:**
Later in the same paper, they use the integral identity: 
$$
\int_{\mathcal{I}^+_>} du \wedge du_\Sigma \wedge V = \int_{\mathcal{I}^+_>}(u-u_\Sigma)du \wedge dV = -\int_{\Sigma}u_\Sigma d\Delta U.
$$

**Attempt as solution**

Starting with the first term, we swap $du$ and $du_\Sigma$ (and the minus sign) and perform the integration to the future of the cut:
$$
-\int_{u_\Sigma}^udu_\Sigma \int_{\Sigma} du \wedge V = -\int_{\Sigma}(u-u_\Sigma)du \wedge V = -\int_{\Sigma} udu \wedge dV - \int_{\mathcal{I}^+_>} du_\Sigma \wedge du \wedge V - \int_{\Sigma} u_\Sigma du \wedge dV
$$
In the last step, we used Stoke's thm: $\int_\Omega d\omega = \int_{\partial \Omega}\omega$.

This is where I am stuck though, and I would appreciate any hints as to how this is done.